# Is it possible to place image in expandable list?

Tags: android

I am new to android application. I need to know whether is it possible to place image in expandable list view as a child for one parent alone. remaining child can be text..

Please help me..

Comment: Seriously, u just want to know that thing is possible or not !!!!

Comment: yes, ofcourse..i need to implement in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can place any kind of View element into the expandable list, including Layouts and ImageViews.